# subprocess.CalledProcessError died with <Signals.SIGSEGV: 11>

Tags: python, pytorch

Excuse me, there is a problem that has troubled me for a long time. I want to run MOTRv2 from GitHub. But it always throws a problem as following:
(motrv2) dcy@ubuntu:~/MOTRv2$ ./tools/train.sh configs/motrv2.args
'my_bash_echo'

- python -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node=8 --use_env main.py --meta_arch motr --dataset_file e2e_dance --epoch 5 --with_box_refine --lr_drop 4 --lr 2e-4 --lr_backbone 2e-5 --pretrained mot/r50_deformable_detr_plus_iterative_bbox_refinement-checkpoint.pth --batch_size 1 --sample_mode random_interval --sample_interval 10 --sampler_lengths 5 --merger_dropout 0 --dropout 0 --random_drop 0.1 --fp_ratio 0.3 --query_interaction_layer QIMv2 --query_denoise 0.05 --num_queries 10 --append_crowd --det_db det_db_motrv2.json --use_checkpoint --output_dir .
- tee -a output.log
  | distributed init (rank 2): env://
  | distributed init (rank 1): env://
  | distributed init (rank 3): env://
  | distributed init (rank 5): env://
  | distributed init (rank 0): env://
  | distributed init (rank 4): env://
  | distributed init (rank 7): env://
  | distributed init (rank 6): env://
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data1/dcy/anaconda3/envs/motrv2/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
  "**main**", mod_spec)
  File "/data1/dcy/anaconda3/envs/motrv2/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
  exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/data1/dcy/anaconda3/envs/motrv2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py", line 260, in 
  main()
  File "/data1/dcy/anaconda3/envs/motrv2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py", line 256, in main
  cmd=cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/data1/dcy/anaconda3/envs/motrv2/bin/python', '-u', 'main.py', '--meta_arch', 'motr', '--dataset_file', 'e2e_dance', '--epoch', '5', '--with_box_refine', '--lr_drop', '4', '--lr', '2e-4', '--lr_backbone', '2e-5', '--pretrained', 'mot/r50_deformable_detr_plus_iterative_bbox_refinement-checkpoint.pth', '--batch_size', '1', '--sample_mode', 'random_interval', '--sample_interval', '10', '--sampler_lengths', '5', '--merger_dropout', '0', '--dropout', '0', '--random_drop', '0.1', '--fp_ratio', '0.3', '--query_interaction_layer', 'QIMv2', '--query_denoise', '0.05', '--num_queries', '10', '--append_crowd', '--det_db', 'det_db_motrv2.json', '--use_checkpoint', '--output_dir', '.']' died with <Signals.SIGSEGV: 11>.

---

Setting OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable for each process to be 1 in default, to avoid your system being overloaded, please further tune the variable for optimal performance in your application as needed.

---

- cleanup
- echo 'Packing source code'
  Packing source code
- rmpyc
  ++ find -name **pycache**
- rm -rf ./**pycache** ./datasets/**pycache** ./models/**pycache** ./models/ops/functions/**pycache** ./models/ops/modules/**pycache** ./models/structures/**pycache** ./util/**pycache**
  ++ find -name '*.pyc'
- rm -rf
- echo ' ...Done'
  ...Done

I tried several times to solve this problem but failed.
My environment is Ubuntu-18.04, python=3.7, torch=1.7.1, Cuda=11.1.
How to solve it?